# Field contains multiple values, I need to query on just one?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2010

I have an access database that has one column that contains multiple strings as below

```
Header
MultipleStrings
Does,Not,Query
```

I need to query based off of a single value I.E if I query "Does" this would pull the row containing the Does,Not,Query.

Below is the code I have tried (commented out is what doesn't work)

```
string strCon = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\Users\mydocs\Documents\Database4.accdb;";
//string strSql = "select ID, TestField, TestField3 from Table1 where MultipleStrings like'" + ThisVar + "'";
string strSql = "Select * from Table1";

using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(strCon))
using (OdbcDataAdapter dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(strSql, con))
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    dadapter.Fill(table);

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

Basically, I don't want it to show the `MultipleStrings` column - but I want to filter the rows based of the value in this column, I assumed I'd use like a `Contains` or `like` query, however this does not seem to work and returns no rows at all.

Update: -

I have tried the following as per suggestions:

```
string strSql = "select * from Table1 where MultipleStrings LIKE '@Search'";
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(strCon))
using (OdbcDataAdapter dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(strSql, con))
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    dadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Search", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + ThisVar + "%";
    dadapter.Fill(table);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

This is still returning a blank row with nothing in it.

Final Answer: -

```
ThisVar = "Query";
string strCon = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\Users\MyDocs\Documents\Database4.accdb;";
string strSql = "select ID,TestField,TestField3,TestCheck,TestCheck2 from Table1 where MultipleStrings LIKE '%"+ThisVar+"%'";
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(strCon))
using (OdbcDataAdapter dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(strSql, con))
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    dadapter.Fill(table);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

TL;DR - Access DB Query that can pull a singular string from a group of strings separated via a ","

Comment: Use like *'"+var+"'*";

Comment: But this final answer is completely vulnerable to SQL Injection and you should use parameterized queries. I'm wondering how my suggested parameterized answer didn't work for you but this!? they are both same. It maybe because the `'` around the ` `'@Search'`.

Comment: @S.Akbari The `'` around `'@Search'` had to be present or when executing the code the microsoft ODBC parameter expected error would occur, maybe I'm formatting it wrong as I am rather new to C# and this is my first time trying to query an Access database. Using your code in your format would not even compile. Finally SQL Injection is not something that I am really concerned with for this in the end product I am using it for obviously for future best practice I will bare this in mind. The Database is going to be on a machine and they only change their own data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use * which allows to match any string of any length 
Use like *'"+var+"'*";

Comment: Need to add asterisk after like and after "'

Comment: Apologies but I don't quite understand what you mean do you mean 
`LIKE "*'" + ThisVar "*'";` ?

Comment: It should be like '%"+your variable+"%'"

Comment: `string strSql = "select ID,TestField,TestField3,TestCheck,TestCheck2 from Table1 where MultipleStrings LIKE '%"+ThisVar+"%'";` this worked, thank you very much

Comment: @badatseesharp  Welcome

Answer (score 1):

Use `Like` and don't forget to add `%`. Also use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid SQL Injection. Like this:

```
string strSql = "select * from Table1 where MultipleStrings LIKE @Search";
...
using (OdbcDataAdapter dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(strSql, con))
{
    dadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Search", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + ThisVar + "%";
    ...
```